# Why does the W3C advise wrapping input elements in <p> tags?

Tags: html, forms, w3c, semantic-markup

I've seen a lot of examples on the web where forms are laid out like so:

```
<form>
    <p><input></p>
</form>
```

To my surprise, this is also described in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element):

> Any form starts with a form element, inside which are placed the
> controls. Most controls are represented by the input element, which by
> default provides a one-line text field. To label a control, the label
> element is used; the label text and the control itself go inside the
> label element. Each part of a form is considered a paragraph, and is
> typically separated from other parts using p elements. Putting this
> together, here is how one might ask for the customer's name:

Though this section is non-normative, it still seems to me that this is bad practice and not semantic. I suppose that the purpose is to put inputs on their own line, but shouldn't the display of these elements be controlled using CSS?

Is there a reason why the W3C advises forms be laid out this way? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are writing a form in a meaningful (read: semantic) way, you will want the flow of text to lead to the element:

```
<form>
 <p><label for="firstName">Please enter your first name:</label><input id="firstName" type="text" /></p>
</form>
```

An even better way is to treat your form like a [mad-libs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Libs#Format) script:

```
<form>
  <p>Hello. My <label for="firstName">name</label> is <input id="firstName" type="text" />...</p>
</form>
```

A `p` element isn't the only way to mark-up a form. If a matrix of data is being added/edited, it's semantically valid to use a table.

In other cases, you might *not* want to use a wrapping element. It depends on what ***content*** you want to be serving up. Worry about styling it all *after* you've got your content sorted out.

Comment: I like your second example. That definitely reads like something you would call a paragraph.

Comment: My main point of confusion is that in the example given on the W3C page the use of `<p>` in this case is purely for presentation. HTML5 brings forth a host of tags such as `<address>` and `<time>` which are supposed to confer semantic meaning to markup and yet the spec makes inputs and paragraphs equivalent.

Comment: @Radu, <aside>`address` had been around before HTML5.</aside> The meaning of the content you create is determined by how it is read. A list of commands could be an unordered list, or could be a series of paragraphs, all depending on context. A form is typically a list of requests: Name__, Email__, Password__, Repeat Password__, etc. If you want it to read as a single fluid paragraph, use one. If you want it to read as a list, use `ul`. If you want it to read as a set of statements, use multiple `p` elements. If you want it to read as a set of name-value pairs, use a `table`. It's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

INPUT elements are inline, and therefore it makes sense to wrap them in some sort of block element, so that there is a natural separation between them.  Since the DIV has no margins by default, it makes sense to use a paragraph.

Comment: The fieldset tag is a form-specific, block-level element that was designed for grouping form elements. It does a very nice job.

Comment: By default a fieldset has a border though.  Of course it can be styled to whatever, but I find a paragraph actually fits more naturally with the rest of the flow of the page.  But yes, fieldset is an option.

Comment: Fieldset has certain drawbacks, like not being able to use flexbox styling

Answer (score 4):

None of the leading CSS, HTML, and grid frameworks is using `P` tags.

See here: [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) or [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/forms.html).

IMHO, use [fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) and divs.

While W3C recommend using paragraph tags `<p>`, it makes little to no sense to follow their advice. The reason is: you are restricting yourself. That is: if you write your components using `p` tags you won't be able to put a div inside it. *[Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)*

well, why would you want to put a div inside a `p` tag? well... why not? for example you want to style your content in a way, or add some information. Using `p` tags you are stuck now. It seems to be bad advice as well to me.

The answer:

> worry about styling once you got your content sorted out

It kind of assumes that you know what you will need in, say, one year from now.

My advice: you don't want to be like:

"I wish I hadn't used the restrictive `P` tags"

Answer (score 1):

This goes for HTML 4, but maybe not for the requested HTML 5.

Ref.: *[17.3 The FORM element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM)*

`form` needs a block-level element as child. `input` is an inline element. The `p` does the trick.

Comment: `form` is *allowed* to have block-level elements, but it doesn't restrict it from containing inline elements in any way.

Comment: @Radu CSS does not change the type of an element, just the way the browser should render it.

Comment: @Shi That's how it was in HTML 4. The current HTML standard states that the content model for FORM elements is "Flow content" which also includes inline elements.

Comment: @Shi, sorry, I moved my comment.

Comment: The [`<p>` example in the proposed HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) includes the same type of usage