# How to make a label appear on the same line and floated to the right

Tags: html, css, layout

**What currently happens:**

```
<div title="Oscillator Parameters">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom:0px">Oscillator Parameters:</h3>

    <label for="oscFreq" style="float:left; display: inline;">Frequency: </label>
    <input class="field" id="oscFreq" value="10" style="float:left; width: 4em; margin-right:2px; display: block; clear: left">
    <p style="display: inline; float: left; margin-top: 0px" class="units">MHz</p>

    <label for="gSense" style="display: inline;clear: none;">G-Sense: </label>
    <p style="float: right; margin-bottom: 0px; clear: right;margin-top: 0px;" class="units">MHz</p>
    <input class="field" id="gSense" value="10" style="float:right; width: 4em; margin-right: 2px; display: block;">
                    
</div>
```

With the above code the elements look like this:
[image: HTML elements]

Adding `float: right;` to the G-sense label makes it look like this (doesn't work):
[image: HTML elements 2]

**What I want to do:**
Make the G-sense label, field and units to appear the same as the frequency elements, but the G-sense elements must be on the right side.

**How can I move them to the right?**
Thanks

Comment: `float` is not designed for this. Use [a grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids).

Comment: General advice: If you want to move three elements, keeping their relative position to each other, wrap them in a parent element (div) and move *that*  element.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the advice.. I've been slowly taking your advice. This is part of a bigger toolbar and the whole thing was originally 1 div lol, slowly grouping elements together. I also took Quentin's advice to use a grid instead of float. (ie. I made this section into a grid with each group of elements as a div

Comment: Inline styles are a terrible way to work. Please migrate your styles to CSS classes for reusability and easier interpretation of the layout.

Comment: @isherwood They already are, but thanks. Much easier to edit layout with inline styles then move them to my css file afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Make the div `position: relative` and then the `<label>` style should be `position:absolute` and `right: 0`, maybe `top: 0` too

Answer (score 0):

Solved by converting the section into a grid and using that instead of float

```
<div id="osc_params" title="Oscillator Parameters">
    <div id="title_osc_param">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom:0px">Oscillator Parameters:</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="osc_freq_grid">
        <label for="oscFreq" id="osc_freq_label">Frequency: </label>
        <input class="field" id="oscFreq">
        <p id="osc_freq_units" class="units">MHz</p>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: 2; grid-row: 2"><!--Empty Div for layout--></div>
    <div id="gsense_grid">
        <label for="gSense" id="gsense_label">G-Sense: </label>
        <p id="gsense_units" class="units">MHz</p>
        <input class="field" id="gSense">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap label and input in a p if it has a semantic meaning:
[Why does the W3C advise wrapping input elements in <p> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934452/why-does-the-w3c-advise-wrapping-input-elements-in-p-tags)

```
<div title="Oscillator Parameters">
  <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px">Oscillator Parameters:</h3>
  <p style="display: inline; float: left">
      <label for="gSense" style="display: block">Frequency: </label>
      <input class="field" id="oscFreq" value="10" style="float:left; 
       width: 4em; margin-right:2px; display: block; clear: left">Mhz
  </p>
  <p style="display: inline; float: right">
      <label for="gSense" style="display: block">G-Sense: </label>
      <input class="field" id="gSense" value="10" style="width: 4em; 
       margin-right: 2px" />Mhz
  </p>
</div>
```